# Part-select a multidimensional systemverilog array as a 1D vector

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I am trying to part-select a 2D packed array as a 1D vector.  I thought that packed arrays are stored contiguously and as such can be treated as a 1D vector.  But is it illegal to access the array this way or am I overlooking something?

I have a few examples where assigning multidimensional array this way works without warnings.  But it looks like accessing them this way is not allowed.

Please take a look at this piece of code to see what I mean.  `arr` shows `X` values when the code is run.  Questa on my local machine and [Aldec on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/24rU) both report out of range warning.

```
// Code your testbench here
// or browse Examples
module tb;  
  logic [2:0][7:0] TEMP = {{8'h22},{8'h11},{8'h00}};
  logic [11:0] arr;
  bit clk;
  initial begin
     #30 $finish;
  end
  initial begin
    forever clk = #5 ~clk;
  end
  always_ff@(posedge clk)
    begin
      arr <= TEMP[12+:12]; //warns and doesn't work
      //arr <= TEMP[0+:12]; //warns but works!!
      TEMP[2:1] <= TEMP[1:0];
      TEMP[0] <= TEMP[2];
    end
  always_ff@(posedge clk)
    begin
      $display("arr : %h", arr);
      $display("TEMP[0] : %h",TEMP[0]);
      $display("TEMP[1] : %h",TEMP[1]);
      $display("TEMP[2] : %h",TEMP[2]);
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a 2-D packed array, but only select one dimension, that refers to the first dimension, just like an unpacked array. Packed arrays are assignment compatible with 1-d packed arrays, But you still need to provide the correct array indices.

There are a number of things you can do to access your 2-D array as a 1-D array.

You can use a part select of a concatenation

```
arr = {TEMP}[0+:12];
arr = s.
```

You can declare your packed array inside a packed structure. Then the structure as a whole is treated as a 1-D array.

```
struct packed {logic [2:0][7:0] TEMP;} s = {{8'h22},{8'h11},{8'h00}};
arr = s[0+:12];
arr = s.TEMP[0]; // if you want to access the array
```

There is also a packed union, which gives you multiple way of accessing the same packed 1-d array

```
   union packed {
                  logic [2:0][7:0] TEMP;
                  logic [5:0][3:0] NIB;
                } u = {{8'h22},{8'h11},{8'h00}};

   arr = u[0+:12];
   arr = u.NIB[2:0];// also 12 bits
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. arr = {TEMP}[12+:12]; still is not able to index into the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `TEMP` as

```
logic [2:0][7:0] TEMP
```

you are declaring a 2D packed array. The outer dimension has 3 elements; the inner dimension has 8 elements.

As it is a packed array, you can also consider it as a 24-bit number. However, when you index `TEMP` you are indexing the outer dimension. So, `TEMP[12]` is element 12 of the outer dimension. But there is no element 12 of the outer dimension (the elements are numbered 2:0). Hence you get your warning and also your `X`s. (As is the case in Verilog) when you index an out-of-range element, the default value of the type is returned, which in this case, as the type is `logic`, is an `X`.

So, when you say

```
  arr <= TEMP[12+:12]; //warns and doesn't work
```

you are setting `arr` to elements 23:12 of `TEMP`. All these elements are out of range, so you just get `X`s (it "doesn't work"). However, when you say

```
  arr <= TEMP[0+:12]; //warns but works!!
```

you are setting `arr` to elements 11:0 of `TEMP`. Elements 2:0 are in range and so return the actual values of `TEMP`, but elements 11:3 are out of range, so `X`s are returned. However, as this is a packed array, `arr` is being set to `96'hXXXXXXXXX210` (or whatever) and as `arr` is 12 bits wide, all the `X`s are truncated and so your code "works".